# Problem searching with blank space in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, search, input, filter

I have a problem with input search field in vue.js.

In my data I have nested arrays, which have titles. When I search the titles and hit space, nothing appears. And titles should be searched with spaces. For example I have a title "Pencils in store" and when I write "Pencils" in input, it does appear with all other information. When I write "Pencils in" nothing appears. Also, in some of the titles I can't reach to the blank space, results appears only while I write "Pen". Here is my code, I have tried with trim and split, but it did not work.
Very thanks in advance!

```
computed: {
getfiltered() {
    const search = this.search;
    return (
    this.categories.filter(category =>
    category.title.includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    category.infos.some(info => info.name.includes(search)
    )
  )
)
},
```

---

Here is the input field

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
   <div v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in getfiltered" :key="categoryIndex">
     <h2>{{category.title}}</h2>
   </div>
```

---

And the data

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    search: '',
      categories: [
         {
           title: 'Pencils in store',
           infos: [{name:'Bic'},
                   {name:'Crayola'}]
          }, //...and so on
```

Comment: Should be сategory.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()). There are no reasons why "Pencils in" won't work this way, unless there are inconsistent whitespaces that need to be normalized. It's unclear what's the deal with "Pen". If you need to not match partial words then you can split to arrays and check if one is a subset of another one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved in a way that @Estus Flask commented.
сategory.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())